# How to display divs and nested divs using href target?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a menu of type like this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the one provides more options below it when clicked. Using some available example code that only uses html and css I could make something like this however I am encountering a problem.

Here's the code:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.target {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.target>div {
  display: none;
}

.target>div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr>
      <a href="#Option1">
                    Options
                  </a>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="target">
  <div id="Option1">
    <a href="#Option1.0">Option 1</a>
  </div>

  <div id="Option1.0">

    <div id="Option1.1">
      Option 1.1
    </div>

    <div id="Option1.2">
      Option 1.2
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epnrsum8/1/).

Now this code seems to work fine however when clicking Option1, Options 1.1 and 1.2 will be displayed, however Option1 will disappear which is not what I want.

How can I keep Option1 visible with 1.1 and 1.2 below it?

https://jsfiddle.net/epnrsum8/1/][3](https://jsfiddle.net/epnrsum8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just missed out adding the text Option 1 in the HTML underneath the Option1.0 div

```
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <hr>
              <a href="#Option1">
                Options
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

<div class="target">
    <div id="Option1">
         <a href="#Option1.0">Option 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Option1.0">
    Option 1
            <div id="Option1.1">
            Option 1.1
            </div>          

            <div id="Option1.2">
            Option 1.2
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is your [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddie19/y263m940/) updated

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a bit of JavaScript to your code as below :

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr>
            <a href="#Option1">Options</a>
            <br>
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="target">
    <div id="Option1">
        <a onclick ="document.getElementById('Option1.0').style.display='block'">Option 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Option1.0">
        <div id="Option1.1">Option 1.1</div>        

        <div id="Option1.2">Option 1.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but problem is it stays visible indefinitely when selecting other options.